# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Network Manager cannot add VPN - greyed out

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to add a [**VPN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) to my network, but the option is greyed out.

Screenshot of the greyed-out indicator
[image]

I installed `network-manager-openvpn` but still no luck. Editing my connection does not show any VPN settings or tabs.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction!

**EDIT**: In case anyone else has this issue, the wording "Add A VPN Connection" is super misleading as it's telling you that *you need to add a VPN connection*, not that you are supposed to click to add one from there.

So select Edit Connections, Add, and then select your VPN from there.

Comment: Can you add one from Settings -- > Network and clicking the + icon?

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes that works fine!

Comment: Does anyone have clues why the entry shown in the image is disabled?

Comment: still greyed out? Same with "configure vpn" after having added a connection.

Comment: Did you install `network-manager-openvpn` ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue, the wording "Add A VPN Connection" is super misleading as it's telling you that *you need to add a VPN connection*, not that you are supposed to click to add one from there.

So select Edit Connections, Add, and then select your VPN from there.

Comment: Wow ... I consider myself a "power-user" but this had me googling for a while. Thank you!

Comment: No amount of intelligence can save you from bad UI design

Answer (score 9):

I recently set up VPN on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS for the first time. This is what I had to do:

```
sudo apt install openvpn
sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

I used network-manager-openvpn-gnome instead of network-manager-openvpn to get the option to import the VPN configuration files.

After that I could go to:

1. **Edit Connections** at the bottom of the menu
2. Click on the <kbd>Add</kbd> button on the next window
3. **Choose Connection type**
4. **Import a saved VPN configuration**

[image]

After that I was able to edit the VPN connection by

1. **Edit Connections**... at the bottom of the menu
2. Select the VPN connection I want to edit
3. Click on the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I actually answered my own question before you posted :) Upvote because your answer will help anyone else who finds this page. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The easy way is using a command on terminal:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

nm-applet normally starts at login by the desktop session manager and does not need to be run manually.

In some versions of Ubuntu there were problems in the security policy.

To solve this you should edit the file 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy' on /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy
```

And change this action:

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own">
.
.
.
<allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
```

to

```
<allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
```

Then restart network-manager

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Comment: Strange -- I used the same settings on 20.04 using the Network Setting control control panel and yet "Add" remained greyed out. Just running `nm-connection-editor` worked!